# Multiple BLE device testing

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have to test Ble devices with an App on iOS and Android, the scenario is having multiple device sending signals and it is difficult to figure out which device is connecting to what phone.

Is there a better way to test and what are some of best tools for checking the status of ble devices like signal strength and other characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [LightBlue Explorer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8) to poke at BLE devices to see characteristics and values. It can also emulate devices once it's seen a real one.

I ultimately ended up writing my own Device Simulator on iOS. This lets me generate a controlled BLE service/characteristic, with full control of the device name, advertised broadcast name, and characteristic values.